# Python's multiprocessing is not creating tasks in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I am learning about multithreading in python using the multiprocessing library. For that purpose, I tried to create a program to divide a big file into several smaller chunks. So, first I read all the data from that file, and then create worker tasks that take a segment of the data from that input file, and write that segment into a file. I expect to have as many parallel threads running as the number of segments, but that does not happen. I see maximum two tasks and the program terminates after that. What mistake am I doing. The code is given below.

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(segment, x):
    fname = getFileName(x)
    writeToFile(segment, fname)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    with open(fname) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    jobs = []
    for x in range(0, numberOfSegments):
        segment = getSegment(x, lines)
        jobs.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(segment, x)))
        jobs[len(jobs)-1].start()
    for p in jobs:
        p.join
```

Comment: FYI, you forgot to call `join`, so the program isn't actually blocking on those `Process`es explicitly (it will happen implicitly unless they're `daemon`s).

Comment: I did call join, see the last two lines of the code.

Comment: You referenced it. You didn't _call_ it. `p.join` is _very_ different from `p.join()`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Spoiled about not putting brackets after programming with Scala :).

Answer (score 0):

`Process` gives you one additional thread (which, with your main process, gives you two processes). The call to `join` at the end of each loop will wait for that process to finish before starting the next loop. If you insist on using `Process`, you'll need to store the returned processes (probably in a list), and join every process in a loop after your current loop.

You want the `Pool` class from `multiprocessing` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)